# Is performance of List.Sort() by Comparison is better than custom IComparer?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, icomparer

I am creating a custom sorting a list of integers. I tried both: using Comparison and custom IComparer:

with comparison:

```
public int ComparisonMethod(int x, int y)
    {
        //just for testing
        return 1;// just for test
    }

List.Sort((x, y) => ComparisonMethod(x,y));
```

With custome IComparer:

```
public class Comparer : IComparer<int>
        {
            public int Compare(int x, int y)
            {
                //just for testing
                return 1;// just for test
            }
        }

var comparer = new Comparer();
List.Sort(comparer);
```

Both Custom Comparer and Comparison have same logic code, but I was suprised  that the performance of sorting by Comparison is better than Comparer. Why the performance of Comparison is better? Or I was wrong about that?

Regard!

Comment: Looking at the IL I have to say I'm surprised at your findings (dotnetfiddle) . A few things to check before you can make a verdict on performance: try to test individually, so both sorting algorithms start with the same exact data (or change the order of tests between runs). Also, if not entering a real comparison method, I think you can get weird results, especially if you "seed" the list with Random values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got curious about your statement so I've put together a benchmark using the widely-adopted [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace perftest
{
#if NETCOREAPP2_1
    [CoreJob]
#else
    [ClrJob]
#endif
    [RankColumn, MarkdownExporterAttribute.StackOverflow]
    public class Benchmark
    {
        class Comparer : IComparer<int>
        {
            public int Compare(int x, int y)
            {
                return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0;
            }
        }

        static int ComparisonMethod(int x, int y)
        {
            return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0;
        }

        Comparison<int> _comparisonDelegate;
        IComparer<int> _comparer;
        List<int> _data, _tempData;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            var random = new Random(0);
            _comparisonDelegate = ComparisonMethod;
            _comparer = new Comparer();
            _data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(_ => random.Next()).ToList();
            _tempData = new List<int>(_data.Count);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int Delegate()
        {
            var result = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.Count; i++)
                result += _comparisonDelegate(_data[0], _data[i]);
            return result;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int Interface()
        {
            var result = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.Count; i++)
                result += _comparer.Compare(_data[0], _data[i]);
            return result;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int SortUsingDelegate()
        {
            _tempData.Clear();
            _tempData.AddRange(_data);
            _tempData.Sort(_comparisonDelegate);
            return _tempData[0];
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int SortUsingInterface()
        {
            _tempData.Clear();
            _tempData.AddRange(_data);
            _tempData.Sort(_comparer);
            return _tempData[0];
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmark>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

.NET Core 2.1

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.1, OS=Windows 7 SP1 (6.1.7601.0)
Intel Core2 Duo CPU T9500 2.60GHz, 1 CPU, 2 logical and 2 physical cores
Frequency=2532763 Hz, Resolution=394.8257 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=2.1.402
  [Host] : .NET Core 2.1.4 (CoreCLR 4.6.26814.03, CoreFX 4.6.26814.02), 64bit RyuJIT
  Core   : .NET Core 2.1.4 (CoreCLR 4.6.26814.03, CoreFX 4.6.26814.02), 64bit RyuJIT

Job=Core  Runtime=Core  

             Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Rank |
------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-----:|
           Delegate |   8.152 us | 0.0087 us | 0.0073 us |    2 |
          Interface |   7.476 us | 0.0462 us | 0.0409 us |    1 |
  SortUsingDelegate | 103.914 us | 0.0728 us | 0.0608 us |    4 |
 SortUsingInterface |  95.900 us | 0.6673 us | 0.5915 us |    3 |
```

.NET Framework 4.7.2

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.1, OS=Windows 7 SP1 (6.1.7601.0)
Intel Core2 Duo CPU T9500 2.60GHz, 1 CPU, 2 logical and 2 physical cores
Frequency=2532763 Hz, Resolution=394.8257 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host] : .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3163.0
  Clr    : .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3163.0

Job=Clr  Runtime=Clr  

             Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Rank |
------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-----:|
           Delegate |   9.677 us | 0.0095 us | 0.0079 us |    2 |
          Interface |   9.126 us | 0.0252 us | 0.0236 us |    1 |
  SortUsingDelegate | 178.287 us | 0.3618 us | 0.2825 us |    4 |
 SortUsingInterface | 174.389 us | 1.5997 us | 1.3358 us |    3 |
```

This contradicts your findings: comparing using interface tends to be a tiny bit faster than comparing by delegate.

The difference must arise from the fact that an interface method call (kind of a virtual method call) is implemented differently than a delegate call in .NET.